# Question about Projective Value Measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

Nielsen and Chuang define a projective measurement as an observable $M$ which has spectral decomposition

$$\sum_m mP_m$$

Where the $m$'s are $M$'s eigenvalues and each $P_m$ is a projection on to $M's$ $m-$eigenspace.

We're given that $M$ itself is self-adjoint, but my question is: are the $P_m$'s also self-adjoint? Or not necessarily?

As a follow-up if the answer is no: how should I understand $P_m^\dagger$ ?

Comment: Does WP help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra) ? This should give you some idea what projections are and how they generalize to infinite-dimensional vector spaces (i.e., Hilbert spaces). Also, could you add more context? An observable on a (separable?, infinite-dimensional?) Hilbert space I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spectral projectors are *always* self-adjoint. If you're familiar with Dirac's notation, one way to see it is that (apart from degeneracy),
$$
P_{m}=\left|m\right\rangle \left\langle m\right|
$$
More in the abstract, linear projectors are defined as endomorphisms for which,
$$
P^{2}=P
$$
So their spectrum is very simple:
$$
P\left|\psi\right\rangle =\varepsilon\left|\psi\right\rangle 
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\varepsilon^{2}=\varepsilon
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\varepsilon=1\textrm{ or }0
$$
In a way, they are the simplest self-adjoint operators you can build.

Comment: Any reason why Nielsen and Chuang don't seem to point that out explicitly when they introduce projective measurements?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is the so-called "[curse of knowledge,][1]". You learn a subject and you tend to forget how hard it was for you to make all the connections. I agree with you that it's worth pointing out.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge